# How to send RightFax email from RFCOMAPI

Tags: c#, com, rightfax

Here is what I currently have:

```
var faxserver = new FaxServerClass
                    {
                        ServerName = "{server ip}",
                        AuthorizationUserID = @"{my username}",
                        Protocol = CommunicationProtocolType.cpTCPIP,
                        UseNTAuthentication = BoolType.False
                    };
faxserver.OpenServer();

var fax = (Fax) faxserver.get_CreateObject2(@"{my username}", CreateObjectType.coFax);
fax.ToEmailAddress = "{my email}";
fax.IsINLJob = BoolType.False;
fax.EmailSubject = "Some random subject";               
fax.IsProductionFax = BoolType.True; 
fax.Send();
```

This code doesn't throw any exceptions but looking at FaxUtil I see "Problem converting fax body or cover sheet". How can I fix this?

Unfortunatly, this product has very little documentation regarding their API. All I could find is [this](http://objectnotset.blogspot.com/2008/04/sending-fax-emails-through-rightfax.html) link.

Answer (score 3):

You are not able to send emails though the COM API for RightFax. You must use another method such as the integration module.  This is by design of RightFax.